# std::ofstream not writing to file

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write a simple program that logs keystrokes. The problem snippet of the code is as follows.

```
std::ofstream of;
of.open(file_name.c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
if (!of) {
    std::cerr << "can't open output file" << std::endl;
}

while (1) {
    for (char i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
            // this is not writing to the file!
            of << i;
        }
    }
}
//close file
of.close();
```

When I inspect the file it is totally empty. If I was to replace the condition  GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767 with true, then indeed I get some text in the file. If I go back to using an older C-style file writing code then it works correctly. However, I really have to know why this is not functioning as it should.

Comment: Try adding `of.flush();` after `of << i;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `std::ofstream`, My guess is that your data is buffered and not being commited to output file.

First you should know that `of << i;` will inserts data into the stream
and is not actually responsible for writing the data to output file. Soyou should explicitly write the data into hard disk. One way is using `of.close();` after buffering it, but since you are in an infinite loop and probably don't want to call `close()` each iteration and reopen the file again, Best way is using `flush()` function.

> **basic_ostream& flush():** Writes uncommitted changes to the underlying output sequence.

Note that **basic_ostream** is the parent class of **basic_ofstream**

So your code would change like below:

```
while (1) {
    for (char i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
            of << i;
            of.flush();  // Add this line to commit your buffer to output file.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't comment. I don't have enough reputation :(

So I have to propose a solution to help you.

I have tested your program and it works in Visual Studio 2015-Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    string file_name = "out.txt";

    std::ofstream of;
    of.open(file_name.c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    if (!of) {
        std::cerr << "can't open output file" << std::endl;
    }

    while (1) {
        for (char i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
                // this is not writing to the file!
                of << i;
            }
        }
    }
    //close file
    of.close();
}
```

I have opened the file with NotePad++ after three executions and this is the content.
[image]

Maybe the content is not written to the file because it is buffered and you close your program abruptly.